Evitar tranformacion de json en html
Hola estoy implementando un gráfico de tipo candlestick que requiere datos en formato json.
Mi api devuelte datos asi:
[{"Interval":"2024-06-06 18:15:00","Opening":-2.0,"Maximum":0.0,"Minimum":-3.0,"Closing":-1.0},
{"Interval":"2024-06-06 19:50:00","Opening":-10.0,"Maximum":-8.0,"Minimum":-12.0,"Closing":-12.0},
{"Interval":"2024-06-06 19:55:00","Opening":-13.0,"Maximum":-10.0,"Minimum":-16.0,"Closing":-13.0},
{"Interval":"2024-06-06 20:00:00","Opening":-12.0,"Maximum":-12.0,"Minimum":-15.0,"Closing":-14.0},
{"Interval":"2024-06-06 20:05:00","Opening":-13.0,"Maximum":-8.0,"Minimum":-14.0,"Closing":-8.0}]

Uso esto en mi controlador mvc:
@ViewBag.Data = jsondatos;

y esta linea en mi vista:
anychart.data=@ViewBag.Data

Mi grafico aparece en blanco. Examinando el html resultante de la vista los datos aparecen así:
anychart.data=[{&quot;Interval&quot;:&quot;2024-06-06 18:15:00&quot;,&quot;Opening&quot;:-2.0,&quot;Maximum&quot;:0.0,&quot;Minimum&quot;:-3.0,&quot;Closing&quot;:-1.0},
{&quot;Interval&quot;:&quot;2024-06-06 18:20:00&quot;,&quot;Opening&quot;:0.0,&quot;Maximum&quot;:1.0,&quot;Minimum&quot;:-3.0,&quot;Closing&quot;:-1.0},
{&quot;Interval&quot;:&quot;2024-06-06 18:25:00&quot;,&quot;Opening&quot;:0.0,&quot;Maximum&quot;:4.0,&quot;Minimum&quot;:-1.0,&quot;Closing&quot;:0.0},
{&quot;Interval&quot;:&quot;2024-06-06 18:30:00&quot;,&quot;Opening&quot;:1.0,&quot;Maximum&quot;:1.0,&quot;Minimum&quot;:-2.0,&quot;Closing&quot;:0.0},
{&quot;Interval&quot;:&quot;2024-06-06 18:35:00&quot;,&quot;Opening&quot;:-1.0,&quot;Maximum&quot;:-1.0,&quot;Minimum&quot;:-4.0,&quot;Closing&quot;:-3.0}]

Estoy usando C# MVC
Que me falta para evitar esa transformación de datos?

Por defecto ASP codifica los strings con HTML Entities, para obtener el string sin codificar usas @Html.Raw
anychart.data=@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data)

Un detalle importante:
Digamos que tu json es {"prop":"algo"}, al hacer lo que te señalo arriba, lo que llega al cliente es:
anychart.data = {"prop":"algo"} //esto NO es un JSON, es un objeto

Entonces sí anychart.data acepta un objeto todo bien, pero si lo que tú quieres es en realidad enviar un JSON, debes agregar comillas:
anychart.data=@Html.Raw("'" + ViewBag.Data + "'")

Esto se renderizará como:
anychart.data = '{"prop":"algo"}' //esto es un JSON


Gracias por la ayuda. Era lo que me faltaba.

@JoseGonzales Un gusto haber sido de ayuda. Saludo
